# LocalTime truncating trailing 00 values

Tags: java, json, spring, java-time, localtime

The original time value stored in my cassandra DB is : 11:43:00.000000000

I am trying to fetch it in my JSON response as : **11:43:00**

What I am getting is: **11:43**

What I have tried so far in my model class:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
@Getter @Setter @RequiredArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Test {
...
@JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm:ss")
private LocalTime delgtexpytm;
```

AND

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="KK:mm:ss")
private LocalTime delgtexpytm;
```

But both of them are trimming the trailing 00.

Comment: What do you mean by "What I am getting is: 11:43"? How do you "get" it?

Comment: I am getting the response in json format in Postman. Have exposed an endpoint (controller>service) that uses this model class to serialize it to send the response after fetching the data from cassandra.

Comment: Does it matter? Wouldn't the receiver of your JSON understand `11:43` alone? I mean, it’s not only unambiguous, it’s also allowed according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. From `String json = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).writeValueAsString(new Test());` I get `{"delgtexpytm":"11:43:00"}`. So with the `:00` that I understnad that you want. How did you do? Could you please create a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**

Try to override the [`shape`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html#shape--) property to [`STRING`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html#STRING) to specify the JSON type to be used. I guess it should help as long as the following explanation from the JavaDoc for the `shape`:

> Structure to use for serialization: definition of mapping depends on datatype, but usually has straight-forward counterpart in data format (JSON).

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm:ss", shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private LocalTime delgtexpytm;
```

Comment: Tried this as well, didn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try.